# How to add new Status attribute to LDAP user objects

Tags: ldap, openldap

I am trying to add a status attribute on LDAP, just like Active directory in Windows, so I can enable or disable user using status attribute.

anyone can help me how it can be possible on LDAP

Answer (score 1):

Most LDAP server would already have such attribute that would prevent a user from authenticating if he's disabled.

If you just want a status attribute that is specific to your application, you need to either extend the directory server's schema to define and allow such attribute, and then you need to add the attribute to the user entries.

Comment: can you please help how I can create the schema on OpenLDAP ?